# Is my implementation of propagation correct ? X is numpy array of shape(9000,784) and Y is one hot encoded array(9000,10) for mnist

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation, implementation

```
def sigmoid( X ):

     sig= 1/(1+np.exp(-1*X) )
     return sig

def FindCost(output,hypothesis):

      cost = output*-1*np.log(hypothesis) + (1-output)*-1*np.log(1-hypothesis)
      cost = np.sum(cost)/cost.shape[0]
      return cost 


def backpropagation(X,Y):

learningRate = 0.2
iterations = 5
#add bias to input data 
InputDimention = X.shape[1]
Layer1neurons = 20
Layer2neurons = 15
outputNeurons =  Y.shape[1]

#initialize wts
weight1 = np.random.normal(1,1,(InputDimention,Layer1neurons))   #(no of input dimention, no of neuron in layer 1)
weight2 = np.random.normal(1,1,(Layer1neurons,Layer2neurons))   #(no of neuron in layer 1, no of neuron in layer 2)
weight3 = np.random.normal(1,1,(Layer2neurons,outputNeurons))       #(no of neuron in layer 2,no of neuron in layer 3)
bias0 = np.random.normal(1,1,(1,Layer1neurons)) #weight of bias to first neuron
bias1 = np.random.normal(1,1,(1,Layer2neurons))
bias2 = np.random.normal(1,1,(1,outputNeurons))



for i in range(0,iterations):    
    #feed fwd
    net1 = np.matmul(X,weight1) + bias0 
    net1 = sigmoid(net1)
    net2 = np.matmul(net1,weight2) + bias1
    net2=  sigmoid(net2)    
    net3 = np.matmul(net2,weight3) + bias2
    net3 = sigmoid(net3)

    #feed back
    dJ_dnet3 =  (net3 - Y) / len(Y)
    node_delta3 = dJ_dnet3*net3*(1-net3)
    dJ_dw3 = np.matmul(node_delta3.T, net2) 
    dJ_dbias2 = node_delta3.sum(axis=0)


    dJ_dnet2 = np.matmul(node_delta3,weight3.T)
    node_delta2 = dJ_dnet2*net2*(1-net2)   
    dJ_dw2 = np.matmul(node_delta2.T,net1)
    dJ_dbias1 = node_delta2.sum(axis=0)

    dJ_dnet1 = np.matmul(node_delta2,weight2.T)
    node_delta1 = dJ_dnet1*net1*(1-net1)   
    dJ_dw1 = np.matmul(node_delta1.T,X)
    dJ_dbias0 = node_delta1.sum(axis=0)


    weight1 = weight1 - learningRate*dJ_dw1.T
    weight2 = weight2 - learningRate*dJ_dw2.T
    weight3 = weight3 - learningRate*dJ_dw3.T

    bias0 = bias0 - learningRate*dJ_dbias0
    bias1 = bias1 - learningRate*dJ_dbias1
    bias2 = bias2 - learningRate*dJ_dbias2

cost = FindCost(Y,net3)   
print cost
return net3
```